# How to edit the name of a location on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I am creating a Google Map of locations related to a particular topic. Since most of these locations exist within places (e.g., parks and public plazas) which are already listed in Google Maps search results with the name of the larger space, when I place a marker or search by coordinates I get the name of the park the location is in.

I would like to, for example, place a marker on my new Google Map for the "Empty Sky" September 11th memorial which is located within Liberty State Park in New Jersey. But when I go to the location coordinates for this memorial, Google Maps shows it as "1 Audrey Zap Drive" and I can't find a way to add an additional name of "Empty Sky" as a marker on the map I am creating.

Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that if you click the "Edit" link for the map, this will enable editing of all the places stored in the map as well.